# Natural Scrolling in Lubuntu 20.04

Tags: lubuntu, system-settings

Recently, I have installed the **Lubuntu 20.04** and I implemented natural scrolling on Lubuntu 18.04, but how implemented on Lubuntu 20.04, but merging with Qt everything is changed.

Comment: Refer https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.8/keyboard_and_mouse.html?highlight=natural%20scrolling  (Lubuntu manual)

Comment: @guiverc, I read it but it is just for the touchpad. not the mouse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, In the [documents of Lubuntu](https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.8/keyboard_and_mouse.html?highlight=natural%20scrolling) I found a GUI way but that is just for touchpad not the mouse. for setting Natural Scrolling in the both of this way works for me:

1. you can use any text editor but I'm so familiar with **Vim**:

   ```
   sudo vim /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf
   ```
2. then append this line `Option "NaturalScrolling" "true"` to the related device

   - you can see each device by the first line of input method:

     ```
     Section "InputClass"
         Identifier "libinput pointer catchall"
     ```

     this shows the mouse configs because it refers to the pointer it means mouse, or:

     ```
     Section "InputClass"
         Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
     ```

     this shows the *Identifier* refers to the touchpad
3. After adding you should have something like below:

   ```
   Section "InputClass"
       Identifier "libinput pointer catchall"
       MatchIsPointer "on"
       MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
       Driver "libinput"
       Option "NaturalScrolling" "true"
   EndSection
   ```

**Attention**: Just append the option line to the devices you want. do not append it to all identifiers.